# I get exact duplicate rows in access when I add data from a third table to the query

Tags: ms-access

I added all fields from the first table in the query and 2 from the second

I created a join based on an ID number between the first 2 tables. When I ran this query the results were fine. Except that there was no business ID field in the query. So i decided to create a new query similar to the first one however this time I also added a third table and created a join between a different ID lable.

This resulted in alot  of duplicate rows which i can't explain since they match exactly (not one value in the rows is different from the other one above or below no matter which column I pick).

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the ID is *unique* for the first two tables but not for the third.

If you join on a non-unique field and, say, four records have the same value, they will be listed all four - and so will the first two tables, fourfold, with all four identical.

Comment: You are right the second one is not unique. Thanks this solved my issue!